# GDataXMLNode and Umlauts

Tags: ios, xml, gdata

from the following code snippet the value of xmlString is `<ELEMENT NAME="&#xF6;&#xE4;&#xFC;">` instead of `<ELEMNT NAME="öäü">`.

```
GDataXMLElement *element = [GDataXMLNode elementWithName:@"ELEMENT"];

GDataXMLNode *a = [GDataXMLNode elementWithName:@"NAME" stringValue:@"öäü"];

[element addAttribute:a];

[parentElement addChild:element];

GDataXMLDocument *doc = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc] initWithRootElement:parentElement];

NSString *xmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[doc rootElement] XMLString]];
```

I know someone is trying to convert my characters into unicode but they should not be converted because the backend can't handle the additional &.

Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the character encoding with `[doc setCharacterEncoding:@"UTF-8"];` did the trick.